# Operand should contain 1 column(s) about insert into & select

Tags: python, mysql

```
"insert into NodeProfileSections (profile_no, tpl_section_no) 
select (np.profile_no, tps.tpl_section_no)
from NodeProfile np, TemplateProfileSection tps, TemplateProfile tp 
where np.hostname = '%s' AND np.role = '%s' AND tp.tpl_profile_no = tps.tpl_profile_no 
AND tp.tpl_name = '%s' AND tp.role = '%s' AND tps.tpl_section_name = '%s';" 
%(hostname, role, template_name, role, section_name)
```

`error_message = 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)'`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the parenthesis from your inner select.

```
q = """INSERT INTO 
             NodeProfileSections (profile_no,tpl_section_no)
       SELECT
             np.profile_no
             ,tps.tpl_section_no
       FROM
             NodeProfile np
             ,TemplateProfileSection tps
             ,TemplateProfile tp
       WHERE
             np.hostname = '%s'
             AND np.role = '%s'
             AND tp.tpl_profile_no = tps.tpl_profile_no
             AND tpl.tpl_name = '%s'
             AND tp.role = '%s'
             AND tps.tpl_section_name = '%s'
"""
```

Comment: really...thanks too much. But I would like to know how? thank you

Comment: Remove the `(` and `)` from your inner select; since it is not proper SQL syntax.  See the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) for more information.